# When R2 score and MSE are not correlated

Tags: regression, statistics, random-forest, forecasting

I'm training some forecasting models and then, to check performance I see several metrics. It's surprising for me when they are no related, for example:

Let's suppose I'd have two models, A and B.

--> R2(A) > R2(B)  --> So apparently, A performance is better, isn't?

But also:

--> MSE(A) > MSE(B)  --> So, apparently, A have higher errors, then B performance is better.

When this happens, what that it means? Why is causing these differences on the criteria?

All the values are scaled so, even if MSE increases when the sample have bigger values, that shouldn't be a problem in this case. I wonder if the dimension (number of indep. variables) can impact in this misalignment.

Thanks!

Comment: What is SME? Do you mean the mean squared error, MSE?

Comment: @Dave, yes, thanks. It's already edited.

Comment: And are you in a situation where $R^2(A)>R^2(B)$ yet $MSE(A)>MSE(B)?$ // Was "SME" a typo, or is that arrangement of the letters related to what the term is called in Spanish?

Comment: Yes, It happens to me using regressors (at least with LinearRegression and GradientBoostingRegressor)  // SME was a typo, in spanish we use the english term too

Comment: How do you calculate the $R^2$ and $MSE$ for those two models?

Comment: sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error and sklearn.metrics.r2_score.

Comment: Are you doing this on training (in-sample) data or test/validation (out-of-sample) data? // What you mentioned happened is mathematically impossible, so there is something going on with your software implementation. It would help if you discussed in detail what you're doing. A standard requirement on Stack Overflow is a `minimal reproducible example` that let's us see an example of where you encounter this bizarre behavior. Could you please post such an example?

Answer (score 1):

To make it short the relation between R2 and MSE is the following :

\begin{equation}
\textrm{MSE}(y, \hat{y} ) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \hat{y_i})^{2}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\textrm{R}^2(y, \hat{y} ) = 1 - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \hat{y_i})^{2}}{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} (y_i - \bar{y})^{2} }
\end{equation}

R2 is just MSE standatized between -1 and 1 for simplicity. You can't really compare R2 and MSE, you are not on the same scale.

Normally you should find these results :
--> If R2(A) > R2(B) then MSE(A) < MSE(B) or vice versa

Comment: What about if $R^2(A)>R^2(B)$ but also $MSE(A)>MSE(B)$, as the OP seems to indicate happened?

Comment: To my knowledge is not possible @Dave !  Are you sure that the models are the same, in term of variables etc? You can compare two models only when the data engineering is the same but you only change minor things. Example : you can't use different cross validation and compare the results since the explained variance will change etc.I suggest to stay away from machine learning techniques when using simple regression techniques like R2.Also keep in mind that R2 is only used for specific models. It doesn't make sense on XGB for example. If you can give us some more information about the models

Comment: The models are regressors (LinearRegression, RandomForest, GradientBoostingRegressor, etc.) and I use predictions and historical values to calculate the R2 coef, what it is right because I use it to know how much of my prediction it is explicable by the independent variables. I compare the same model structure but with one extra independent variable every time (forward selection model) to decide how many variables I should keep. Then, the models I compare are pretty similar, but data engineering is changed, of course, what would be the sense of comparing two identical models?

Comment: The first flag comes when you try to explain GradientBoostingRegressor with R2. GBR is not a linear model so there is no point on using R2, it just doesn't make sense. Also, there is a big difference between using a model to explain and to predict. R2 is very important on explaining a model however when trying to predict you want to minimse the error, so using RMSE, MSE etc. It always comes down to a matter of what is the final purpose of your model. PS : Don't use R2 to find the best model for predicting something!

Comment: Your last comment contradicts your equations, which (correctly) show $R^2$ to be a monotonic transformation of $MSE$. // $R^2$ makes sense for nonlinear regression models (interpretation is harder, but it’s fine for model comparisons), so I don’t follow your objection.

Comment: I was looking even harder to explain why the R2  is not a good metric for predictive models. I found this question, maybe it will help a little understand why you can have those different results https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228540/how-to-calculate-out-of-sample-r-squared/492581#492581 .... However I stand by what I said, the above equation isn't possible. Between two linear regression models the scale of the R2s and MSEs should be the same (R2(1) vs R2(2) and MSE(1)vsMSE(2)). If not, than there is something missing on the information that you are giving to us

Answer (score 1):

As stated in other answers $\text{MSE}(A) > \text{MSE}(B)$ implies $R^2(A) < R^2(B)$, the derivation is quite straightforward:

$$
\text{MSE}(A) > \text{MSE}(B)
$$
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum{(y_i - a_i)^2} > \frac{1}{n}\sum{(y_i - b_i)^2} 
$$
divide by $\frac{1}{n} \sum{(y_i - \bar{y})^2}$, which is constant greater than 0 (assuming it is not equal to 0) for a given set of $y$-s:

$$
\frac{\sum{(y_i - a_i)^2}}{\sum{(y_i - \bar{y})^2}} > 
\frac{\sum{(y_i - b_i)^2}}{\sum{(y_i - \bar{y})^2}},
$$
multiply by $-1$ (changing the sign) and add 1 result in:
$$
1-\frac{\sum{(y_i - a_i)^2}}{\sum{(y_i - \bar{y})^2}} < 
1-\frac{\sum{(y_i - b_i)^2}}{\sum{(y_i - \bar{y})^2}},
$$
which is:
$$
R^2(A) < R^2(B).
$$

In addition, you should not use $R^2$ to compare different linear regression models using data with **different** number of features due to [$R^2$ inflation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Inflation_of_R2).

Comment: The criticism of $R^2$ in the last sentence does not make sense to me. While it is true that performance metrics can be driven high by overfitting to the training data, that is true for most metrics, including both $MSE$ and $R^2$. [While I have considerable disappointment with how `sklearn` calculates out-of-sample $R^2$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590199/how-to-motivate-the-definition-of-r2-in-sklearn-metrics-r2-score), an out-of-sample $R^2$ makes plenty of sense to me, in which case it is equivalent to out-of-sample $MSE$ (as your answer discusses).

Comment: The optimal value of the objective (MSE) in least squares (without regularisation) is weakly smaller as more explanatory variables are added (and hence additional columns of X are added). Thus, comparing LS regression models trained on different number of features using MSE or R2 does not make much sense. Probably more clear example is that you can not choose number of clusters for kmeans based on total sum of squares (kmeans objective), as the latter strictly decreases as k (number of clusters) increases.

Comment: That’s true in-sample. Out-of-sample, as I was discussing, that  need not be the case, however.

Answer (score 1):

What you’ve described can’t happen in math, so there’s either a missing detail, a bug in your code causing you to input something other than what you intend to input, or something wrong with the function (the last of which I find unlikely).

I [disagree](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590199/how-to-motivate-the-definition-of-r2-in-sklearn-metrics-r2-score) with the `sklearn` implementation of $R^2$, but for the same data set, $R^2_{1,sklearn}>R^2_{2,sklearn}\iff MSE_2>MSE_2\iff R^2_{1,Dave}>R^2_{2,Dave}$. This is because $R^2$, either via the `sklearn` implementation or that way I prefer, is a strictly decreasing function of MSE.

$$R^2=1-\dfrac{MSE}{denominator}$$

(This denominator is some kind of sum of squares that is related to a model that predicts the same value every time. Your function and I disagree on what the one value should be, but you could pick $5$ or $17$ or $\pi$ as the denominator, and MSE and that definition of $R^2$ should move in opposite directions.)

If you evaluate the $R^2$ of two different models but on the same data, the denominator stays the same. Thus, increasing/decreasing $R^2$ corresponds to decreasing/increasing MSE.

(If your implementation of an MSE calculation involves an $n-p$ denominator instead of $n$ or $n-1$, then the above does not apply. This could be the kind of missing detail I mentioned in the last sentence of my first paragraph.)

I have answered this question on [Cross Validated Stack Exchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/592424/247274) and believe in my answer.